# Unformat HDD, windows / linux mess up

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, formatting

So i have an 8TB hard drive, was formatted in Ubuntu and was filled with data that i would give my little finger to be able to recover.

I recently installed Windows 11 in another SDD and when i opened diskmgmt.msc i stupidly accepted to initialize the unititialized hard drives, including this 8TB one.

I have tried running `testdisk` in ubuntu but i can't seem to get any information out of it.

What can i do to recover the data, or at least what i can salvage?

Comment: Probably best to take the drive to a local recovery agency (more expert than most of us) and see what they can reover.

Comment: The solution I found for problems like these was to back up as much of my data as possible to the cloud.  Data stored on one single disk is pretty volatile.

Comment: 8TB of cloud storage would be too expensive for my wallet. I was actually in the process of backing it up to a new 8TB drive i bought when this happened

Comment: Next time, make sure you partition the drive (i.e., have a partition table) instead of formatting it "partitionlessly", even if you need only a single partition. Also, make sure the type code/GUID isn't used/recognized by Windows. Being partitionless was probably why the "accident" could have happened.

Comment: You can use photorec to get some of your data back (contiguous files with a recognslised signature and sans filename information)

Comment: How were you doing the backup?  There is a minute chance we can use the backup to recover the data if you were blocking up a block device.

Comment: I didn't even start, when i opened diskmgmt to check on my new HDD i clicked on "Initialize Hard Drives" and the original one was immediately formatted. I'm trying "Disk Drill" in windows and i'm pretty sure i'm going to be able to recover most of it